# Format data of string of dates and associated values from an unstructured list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tuples

I want to save movie reviews (date and the reviews) obtained from web scraping using beautiful soup into a data frame. There are at least one review for each posted date and there can be several reviews per day.

Thing is, the HTML doesn't have a div structure for each date and associated reviews, but instead each element, dates and reviews are all siblings tags, ordered one after another.

Here a snippet of the html:

```
<div class="more line-bottom"> 
    <a class="next" href="es/news/374528/cat/113418/#cm"> <span>anterior</span> <span class="icon"> </span> </a>
</div>


<div class="date">
    <p>miércoles, 7 de agosto de 2019</p>
</div>

<div class="article clear-block no-photo">
    <div class="box-text-article">
        <p class="news-info">
            <a href="es/newsdetail/376261">
                <span>Dokufest 2019</span> 
            </a>
        </p>
        <h2>
            <a href="es/newsdetail/376261">Crítica: <i>Aether</i></a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="date">
    <p>viernes, 2 de agosto de 2019</p>
</div>

<div class="article clear-block no-photo">
    <div class="box-text-article">
        <p class="news-info">
            <a href="es/newsdetail/376044"><span>Peliculas / Reviews</span> </a>
        </p>
        <h2><a href="es/newsdetail/376044">Crítica: <i>Remember Me (Recuérdame)</i></a></h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article clear-block no-photo">
    <div class="box-text-article">
        <p class="news-info">
            <a href="es/newsdetail/376041"><span>Peliculas / Reviews</span> </a>
        </p>
        <h2><a href="es/newsdetail/376041">Crítica: <i>Animals</i></a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to fetch all the text of interest using a for loop and .next_siblings, but then can only format the obtained text involving many steps. Is there a more pythonic solution that you can suggest?
I have seen other post with solutions that might apply but only if I had a known length of elements. For example using tuples and converting to dictionaries, but since there can be more than one review per date this answers don't apply.

Here is my code to the web scraping and formatting:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

req = requests.get("https://www.cineuropa.org/es/news/cat/113418/")
soup =  BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

# result is the container of the tags of interest.
result = soup.find("div", attrs = {'class':'grid-65'})

# This is the element prior to the list of movie reviews
prior_sib_1st_review = result.find("div", attrs= {'class':"more line-bottom"})
```

Then what a do is use the only attribute present in the date div to differenciate it from the review's tag and add it to the head of a tuple. Since the fetched data is ordered, there always would be a date and then a variable number of reviews title. I add up the titles to the tuple until a new date comes up. I have to do it using try catch because an error rises. The list end ups with some unicode.

```
_list = []
tup = ()
   for sibling in prior_sib_1st_review.next_siblings: 
      try:
          if(list(sibling.attrs.values())[0][0] == "date"):
              tup = (repr(sibling.text),)
          else:
              tup = tup + (repr(sibling.text),)

      except AttributeError as error:
         pass

      _list.append(tup)
```

Problem with this is that I get tuples that start off with the same date and that increment on their length with the for loop. So I remove the empty elements and the one that only contains the date:

```
_list_dedup = [item for item in _list if len(item)>1]
```

Then I group by the dates.

```
 group_list = []
 for key, group in groupby(_list_dedup , lambda x: x[0]):
    group_list.append(list(group))
```

And finally keep the longest tuple of the list, which would be the one containing all the associated reviews for each date.

```
final_list = []
for elem in group_list:
   final_list.append(max(elem))
df_ = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried iterating through all divs, inspecting the class of each, and then storing the most recent date encountered? I think that is the most common solution for a problem like yours. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get("https://www.cineuropa.org/es/news/cat/113418/")
soup =  BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

# result is the container of the tags of interest.
result = soup.find("div", attrs = {'class':'grid-65'})
entries = {}
date = ""
for o in result.find_all('div'):
    if 'date' in o['class']:
        date = o.text
    if 'box-text-article' in o['class']:
        try:
            entries[date].append(o)
        except:
            entries[date] = [o]
print(entries)
```

The result of this sample is a dictionary with dates as keys and lists of BeautifulSoup objects matching the class 'box-text-article'. Since dates always precede their corresponding articles, there's always a date to match. You can add a few lines to get the title, the link, etc. (The try/except bit in the middle just allows you to make a new entry for a date not yet in the dictionary or to append to an existing date entry if it is found.)

Comment: Works awesome. Thanks! The only thing is when adding the values to the date key, you have to put o.text, or else you get the whole tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to produce a nested dict with the outer dict keys being the dates and the inner values being dicts which have the event name as keys and links to reviews as values. It uses `:contains` (required bs4 4.7.1+) to isolate each date section and css filtering to filter out future dates from current date.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

req = requests.get("https://www.cineuropa.org/es/news/cat/113418/")
soup =  BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
base = 'https://www.cineuropa.org' 
listings = OrderedDict()

for division in soup.select('.date'):
    date = division.text
    next_date = soup.select_one('.date:contains("' + date + '") ~ .date')
    if next_date:   
        next_date = next_date.text
        current_info = soup.select('.date:contains("' + date + '") ~ div .box-text-article:not(.date:contains("' + next_date + '") ~ div .box-text-article) a')      
    else:
        current_info = soup.select('.date:contains("' + date + '") ~ div .box-text-article a')
    listings[date] = {i.text:base + i['href'] for i in current_info}

pprint(listings)
```

---

**Only `Crítica`**

If you only want the `Crítica` then you can filter again with `:contains`

```
for division in soup.select('.date'):
    date = division.text
    next_date = soup.select_one('.date:contains("' + date + '") ~ .date')
    if next_date:   
        next_date = next_date.text
        current_info = soup.select('.date:contains("' + date + '") ~ div .box-text-article:not(.date:contains("' + next_date + '") ~ div .box-text-article) a:contains("Crítica:")')      
    else:
        current_info = soup.select('.date:contains("' + date + '") ~ div .box-text-article a:contains("Crítica:")')
    listings[date] = {i.text:base + i['href'] for i in current_info}
```

---

Example `listings` entries (all items):

[image]

Comment: DId you try this?